# Calculate probability and percentage of repetition

Tags: probability, percentages

For an algorithm I want to calculate  probability and percentage of repetition of questions in an exam.

For example: suppose there are 1000 questions in an question bank and 100 candidates are going to appear that exam and according to paper config each candidate will get random 2 questions from that bank.

I want to calculate how many approx. questions may get repeat by considering no. of candidates and questions need to pull for each candidate.

I checked [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), which is considering total questions viz 1000 and randomly picked question viz 2 but what about total candidates? How can I calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let there be $m$ questions, $n$ candidates and let it be that every candidate receives $k$ questions. Define $p:=\frac{k}{m}$ and $q=1-p$.

For every $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ let $Q_i$ be a random variable taking value $1$ if question $i$ is repeated and taking value $0$ otherwise.

Then $\sum_{i=1}^mQ_i$ is the number of questions that will be repeated and by linearity of expectation and symmetry we find:$$\mathbb EQ=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb EQ_i=m\mathbb EQ_i=mP(Q_1=1)$$

Now it remains to find $P(Q_1=1)$.

For that let $X$ denote the number of candidates that will get question $1$. Then $X$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$.

Then: $$P(Q_1=1)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)=1-q^n-npq^{n-1}$$

Proved is now: $$\mathbb EQ=m(1-q^n-npq^{n-1})$$

Comment: I tried m(1-q^n-npq^{n-1}) in excel  by putting actual vales as m=100, n=100, k=1 and p=0.01, q=0.99 so the EQ=26.42380211. What this value means? 
How it will tell how many approx. questions may get repeat or the percentage of repeating questions?

Comment: It is the expected number of questions that will be repeated. So according to your calculations if there are $100$ questions, also $100$ candidates and every candidate gets one question then there will be approximatily $26$ questions that are reached out to more than one candidate. Is that what you were after?

Comment: So in short 26 question may get repeat within the specified bunch of candidate, am I getting it correctly?

Comment: Yes. I would say approximately $26$ questions will be repeated in the sense that more than one candidate will get such a question.

Comment: Great!!! that's working fine with production application.Thanks. I calculated percentage by (EQ/no. of questions)x100. So that it will give how many % of questions may get repeat .

Comment: Now if I manage in my software to NOT to assign/fetch question which is alredy given to some other candidate then How the calculation will change? means How many candidates will get served with that many questions if repetition of questions are NOT allowed?